# "System.ArgumentException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed ". I keep getting this error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle10g

I get this error on the server. I cannot replicate this on my development machine.

I get it when i call ExecuteReader, ExecuteScalar or when i try to fill a dataset.

I use an oracle database.

This, i think, increases when the load on the server increases. Im not sure.

i need help fixing this. Please let me know if you need anymore details.

The code for ExecuteScalar would be as follows

```
Public Function ExecuteScalar1(ByVal sExecuteString As String, ByVal sConnectString     As     String) As String
        Dim OrclCmd As New OracleCommand
        Try
            If OpenConnection(sConnectString) Then
                OrclCmd.CommandText = sExecuteString
                OrclCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                OrclCmd.Connection = OrclConn
                ExecuteScalar_ = Convert.ToString(OrclCmd.ExecuteScalar())
                If ExecuteScalar_ Is System.DBNull.Value Then
                    ExecuteScalar_ = ""
                End If

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Err.Raise(Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description)
        Finally
            Call CloseConnection()
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: is `OpenConnection()` doing `OrclConn.Open()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your `OpenConnection` method do?

I'm assuming it opens a database connection on a completely independant OracleCommand object. I would suggest the simplest solution here would be to pass your OracleCommand object in ByRef to the OpenConnection method, allowing you to associate a connection and open it within the method.

Obviously, this will require you to change the OpenConnection method to take both a ConnectionString parameter, as well as an OracleCommand object by reference, the signature would be:

```
Public Sub OpenConnection(ByVal sConnectionString As String, ByRef orclCommand As OracleCommand)
```

This will allow you to work with the OracleCommand object in both methods, with them both referencing the same object - therefore allowing you to call .Open() on the connection, and have the connection open in both methods.

### Re-reading your code...

You appear to have an object called `OrclConn`, which you assign to `OrclCmd.Connection`.

My psychic debugging tells me this is a Static object declared outside of this Function. If so, there's your problem - when multiple users are accessing this code, the `OrclConn` object can have it's connection closed by another user by the time the command is executed. Typical race condition on a shared object.

The solution would be to use a connection object local to the function:

```
Public Function ExecuteScalar1(ByVal sExecuteString As String, ByVal sConnectString As String) As String
    Dim OrclCmd As New OracleCommand
    Dim OrclConn As New OracleConnection
    Try
        OrclConn.ConnectionString = sConnectString
        OrclConn.Open() 
        'Add any connection initialisation here

        OrclCmd.CommandText = sExecuteString
        OrclCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        OrclCmd.Connection = OrclConn

        ExecuteScalar_ = Convert.ToString(OrclCmd.ExecuteScalar())

        If ExecuteScalar_ Is System.DBNull.Value Then
            ExecuteScalar_ = ""
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Err.Raise(Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description)
    Finally
        If OrclConn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then ' Can't remember if this is correct
            OrclConn.Close()                             ' Just be sure to call this
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaymz i'll surely try this out. Yes OrclConn is declared as     `Private OrclConn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection` . But i dont think its static. I'll try it though.